# SQL "Replace Into" drop some of my rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that replace instead of update.

The columns of my table look like that

```
(id
block
region
login
password
email
business
firstname
name
version
updatable
bodyshop_id
mac
register_date
lastvisite_date
enum_test
address1)
```

and when I run a statement like this:

```
REPLACE INTO `users` (`login`, `firstname`, `region`, `address1`, `enum_test`, `block`, `id`) VALUES ('Samira GO', 'Samira', 'all', 'lmklm', '1', '0', '2')
```

Samira have the id number two. (target of the replace ;) )

The person with the id number one is drop by the request.

(The primary id key of the table is id+login+email)

(When I ask this request to SQL it told me that 3 lines are affect)

If you want to ask, id, login, or email are some primary value, so I don't understand how it would be able to change some value with another id or login

Answer (score 0):

From [the MySQL `REPLACE` doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html):

> The REPLACE statement returns a count to indicate the number of rows affected. This is the sum of the rows deleted and inserted. If the count is 1 for a single-row REPLACE, a row was inserted and no rows were deleted. If the count is greater than 1, one or more old rows were deleted before the new row was inserted. It is possible for a single row to replace more than one old row if the table contains multiple unique indexes and the new row duplicates values for different old rows in different unique indexes.

So, it sounds like one row was inserted and two rows were deleted.

Examine your table definition and see if there are any UNIQUE indexes other than the PRIMARY KEY.  Note also that while you say the primary key is `id, login, email`, your query doesn't specify `email`.  If two rows existed that matched `id` and `login` but had different `email`, they may have both been deleted.

You may also consider that what you wanted to do is [an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of a `REPLACE`.  `REPLACE` functions more like a combined `DELETE` then `INSERT`.